# #DocusignAPI - Fetching Data from Docusign to create Web Page to view status for non admin

Tags: docusignapi

I am not a technical person, i was wondering if it is possible to fetching the information from Docusign pertaining to Status, reminder, Envelope ID, Name etc and Display it on a custom webpage ?

I wish to create a internal company portal where the requesters can view the status of their signature requests and stuff.

Thanks in advance !
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible with DocuSign but if you're not technical I'd recommend outsourcing the work.  This can be done using DocuSign's REST and/or SOAP APIs so you need to be a programmer to do so.  But yes there are API calls you can make to query real-time information and metadata like reminders on the envelope.

The [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) is where developers should start: